# write to a text file from HTML form using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, text

I wrote a html form just with an email field. I want to transfer that email that the user
inputs into a text file on my web server.

When I click on the submit button I get a white screen. Nothing is written to my text file. 
I also want to redirect the user to another page when they click the submit button.
Is this possible? I am a newbie.

```
<?php

$file = fopen("emaillist.txt","a+");
fwrite($file,$email);
fclose($file); 
print_r(error_get_last());

?>

<form action= "emaillist.php" method="post" name="email ">
<input type="text" name="email">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="email" value="submit"><br>
```

Comment: You are depending on `register_globals` being activated. it is not a deprecated and REMOVED mis-feature in PHP. your code is also trying to append to that file, whether a POST was actually performed or not...

Comment: You have two names of the same `<form name="email"` and `<input type="submit" name="email" value="submit">`. For starters, rename your `<form name` to something else.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Andy G said about changing the name of submit button:

```
<?php
//Get the email from POST
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$file = fopen("emaillist.txt","a+");
fwrite($file,$email);
print_r(error_get_last());

//redirect
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
```

Don't leave any blank lines between `<?php` and the beginning of the file, otherwise redirect won't work.

Answer (score 1):

In php theres an array called `$_POST` that stores all of the variables from a form when you post it. So `$email` would be found in `$_POST['email']`

Answer (score 1):

The submission results will be stored in the `$_POST` variable:

```
<?php

$file = fopen("emaillist.txt","a+");

$email = $_POST['email']; 

fwrite($file,$email);
fclose($file); 
print_r(error_get_last());

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Use different name for submit button also check if the submit button was pressed than write to file. You also didn't get the posted `email` values

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $file = fopen("emaillist.txt","a+");
    fwrite($file,$email);
    fclose($file); 
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
?>
<form action= "" method="post" name="form">
<input type="text" name="email">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: `<form name="email "` and `<input type="text" name="email">`? Something is bound to go wrong.

Comment: @Fred yup he was having so many errors in the code, Edited the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few things you'll need to update here:

Form elements need to have different names, so you can differentiate between them in the PHP server-side code.  Something like this:

```
<form action="emaillist.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="emailSubmit" value="submit" />
    <br />
</form>
```

You need to wrap your server-side code in a conditional to make sure it's a form post.  Currently, when you first load this page, it's going to write to the file.  But there's no content until you post back to the page again with the form data.  So you need to check if it's a form post.  A common way to do this is to check for the presence of the submit button in the post data:

```
if (isset($_POST["emailSubmit"])) {
    $file = fopen("emaillist.txt","a+");
    fwrite($file,$email);
    fclose($file); 
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

Just to confirm, since you say you're new to PHP... You're expecting the file to be written on the *server* and not on the *client*, correct?

To redirect to another page, you can simply set the location header in the server-side PHP code.  This needs to be done before any content is emitted to the client.  Since you only want this to happen on a post event, it should be in the same conditional as before:

```
if (isset($_POST["emailSubmit"])) {
    $file = fopen("emaillist.txt","a+");
    fwrite($file,$email);
    fclose($file); 
    print_r(error_get_last());

    header("Location: http://www.yoursite.com/newPage.php") ;
}
```

Comment: Written on the server and not on the client you are correct. Thanks seems like it is working now, I got the redirect working and now just need to put a \n like somewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['emailSubmit'])) {
    $file = fopen('emaillist.txt','a+');
    $email = $_POST['nail'];
    $fmail = $email.PHP_EOL;
    fwrite($file,$fmail);
    fclose($file); 
    print_r(error_get_last());

    header("Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/thanks.html") ;
}

?>
<form action='emaillist.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name ='nail' size= '30'/>
    <br />
    <br />
    <input type='submit' name='emailSubmit' value='OK'/>
    <br />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button and input element and the form, have the same name "email". The first thing to do is to give them different names.

The name of the form also includes an extra space "email ".

Comment: Thank you all. Now I am able to write to a text file. Renaming from email to other names helped. Now all the emails in the text document are on the same line. I know that you need to have a /n in the php code. Not sure where exactly. Also the header tag is not redirecting either even though I have it in the php code. I am not a JEDI YET!!! Thanks guys.

Comment: You mean `\n` ;). Note that the `name` property of a form isn't really used these days. Give the form an `id` though, which can be used by JavaScript.