# Write server text files with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I've been struggling to write server text files with Ajax and would really appreaciate if someone had a moment to take a look. In simple, why doesnt the following code  write 'testdata' to test1.txt?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
alert('done')
  }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","test1.txt",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("testdata");


</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I've successfully been able to read text files with GET. If I replace the 3 key lines with

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","test1.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

it works.

What is wrong with the code above or is this a file permission issue? I am using GoDaddy and given writing permission so that I can modify the above text file with php for example.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Joel

Comment: `xmlhttp.open("POST","test1.txt",true);` post to a PHP script that reads the data & writes the file

Comment: That indeed explains why it doesnt work! Thank you! Do you have any example of the missing PHP-script? I know how to use fwrite but I dont know how PHP gets the data that Ajax posts?

Comment: I don't use PHP, but how about [write to a text file from HTML form using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868399/write-to-a-text-file-from-html-form-using-php)

Answer (score 2):

Got it working now - thanks Alex! These are the working files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
alert('done')
 }
}

xmlhttp.open("POST","phpwrite2.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("name=Joel");


</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And PHP:

```
<?php
$myFile = "ttt.txt";

$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $_POST["name"];
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
?>
```