# how to save input field data to text file without flushing out the textboxes

Tags: html, css, input, progress-bar

I am making a thing for setting goals,and to show your progress, I use the progress element. I would like to save my goal with php/js/other to a .txt file on my server called user.txt. I have already tried this [Write server text files with Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961750/write-server-text-files-with-ajax) and [PHP write file from input to txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998961/php-write-file-from-input-to-txt,This) shows what I want, but instead of form tags, I want just 2 input fields
Is there any way I can merge these 2 files to save my data from my 2 fields to a text file(user.txt)
 Here is my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
  document.getElementById("myProgress").value = x;
}

function myFunction2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea2").value;
  document.getElementById("myProgress").max = x;
}
```

```css
progress {
  color: #0063a6;
  font-size: .6em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-indent: .5em;
  width: 30em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid #0063a6;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Goal Progress:</h3>
<progress id="myProgress" value="0" max="100">
</progress>

<hr>
<input type="text" id="myTextarea"></input>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
<hr>
<input type="text" id="myTextarea2" />
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Set Goal</button>
<hr>
```

Comment: I tried merging the files in the link and my javascript

Comment: I'm not seeing anything about writing to a text file.

Comment: You said you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961750/write-server-text-files-with-ajax) but I'm not seeing it on your sample code...

Comment: whatr im askin is how to merge the two files to do that

Comment: Well try it before asking.

Comment: I did it but I am a js noob

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100784/discussion-between-parseguy-and-hjerem).

Comment: You should look into jQuery AJAX functions in order to save the results to a file on your server. Right now this question is too broad since you have no AJAX or PHP shown.

Comment: I don't know those langs and was hoping you could write a demo file for me that could do what my question asks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I finally solved my perplexing paradyme:

```html
<html>
<body onload="timer=setTimeout('myFunction2(); myFunction();',3000)">
<style>
progress {
  color: #0063a6;
  font-size: .6em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-indent: .5em;
  width: 30em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid #0063a6;
  background: #fff;
}
</style>
<h3>Goal Progress:</h3>
<progress id="myProgress" value="0" max="100">
</progress>

<hr>
<form action="form.php" method="POST">
add money:
<input type ="text" name="field1" id="myTextarea"></input>
<hr>
Goal:
<input type ="text" name="field2" id="myTextarea2"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
<hr>
<button onclick="myFunction2(); myFunction();">show new progress</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    document.getElementById("myProgress").value = x;
}
function myFunction2() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea2").value;
    document.getElementById("myProgress").max = x;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```