# Have a HTML Form output to a .txt file

Tags: php, html, forms, output

so I'm VERY new to all this and I would like to know if what I am asking is possible? I am pretty sure I need some kind of .php file for this. But I really don't know anything about that language. I'm only 13 so please keep it simple if anyone could help?

Here is my HTML code, please note that I am using the foundation form js

```
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Submit.php"> 
<div id="Form">
<div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                <p style="float:left; color:white;">YOUR EMAIL</p>
                  <input name="USER" type="text"  placeholder="YOUR EMAIL" />
                </div>
              </div>


<div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                <p style="float:left; color:white;">FACEBOOK URL</p>
                  <input name="URL" type="text" placeholder="FACEBOOK URL" />
                </div>
              </div>
<br>
<br>
<input type="image" src="Assets/submit.png" name="Submit" alt="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
</form>
```

Comment: you're right that you'll need some PHP to make anything happen. By virtue of saying action="Submit.php" you're going to pass the information you collected in "USER" and "URL" to a script named Submit.php which can process them any way you want, including writing them to a text file.

Comment: Try reading this previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868399/write-to-a-text-file-from-html-form-using-php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$action=$_REQUEST['action']; 
if ($action=="") 
    { 
?>
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action=""> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
<div id="Form">
<div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                <p style="float:left; color:white;">YOUR EMAIL</p>
                  <input name="EMAIL" type="text"  placeholder="YOUR     EMAIL" />
                </div>
              </div>


<div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                <p style="float:left; color:white;">FACEBOOK URL</p>
                  <input name="URL" type="text" placeholder="FACEBOOK     URL" />
                </div>
              </div>
<br>
<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
</form>
<?php
    } 
else 
    { 
    $email=$_REQUEST['EMAIL']; 
    $url=$_REQUEST['URL']; 

    if (($url=="") || ($email==""))

        { 
        echo "Missing required feild, try again"; 
?>
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action=""> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit"> 
 <div id="Form">
<div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                <p style="float:left; color:white;">YOUR EMAIL</p>
                  <input name="EMAIL" type="text"  placeholder="YOUR     EMAIL" />
                </div>
              </div>


 <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                <p style="float:left; color:white;">FACEBOOK URL</p>
                  <input name="URL" type="text" placeholder="FACEBOOK     URL" />
                </div>
              </div>
<br>
<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> 
 </form><?php
        } 
    else{



$dr=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

fwrite(fopen("$dr/names.txt", 'a+' ), PHP_EOL);
fwrite(fopen("$dr/names.txt", 'a+' ), "$email $url");
echo"SUCCESS";

}}
?>
```

This should work, create a file called names.txt and try it out!

EDIT: Cleaned up names.txt a bit

Comment: Hi thank you for writing all this out. Can I confirm that this is all just one document I put this in?

Comment: @Tom correct, no need for submit.php, just names.txt in the root directory ( that can be easily changed, though)

Comment: Hi, it doesn't seem to be working at all if I name the file .php http://www.socialstar.co.uk/NEWSTAR/Signup.php And also doesn't output any text when I name the file .html http://www.socialstar.co.uk/NEWSTAR/Signup.html ?

Comment: @TomBuxton Do you have PHP installed? Edit: also, check the error logs

Comment: I am using a web host. One sec I am sure they have

Comment: Yep they have PHP 5.4 & ASP.NET 4.5.